# How to hide page path - htaccess.conf

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My php web app url structure is:

> www.MyDomain.com/SubFolder_A/SubFolder_B/master.php

I'd hide the **master.php** path.

Here a portion of my **htaccess.conf** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

How could I edit it, to hide my server directory structure?

Comment: why a rewrite? just make `master.php` be the `DirectoryIndex` for that folder.

Comment: could you please provide the url you want to show to user. I don't understand if you want `www.MyDomain.com/` to pointer to master.php or `www.MyDomain.com/master.php`.

Comment: What is `htaccess.conf`? Should it not be `.htaccess`?

Comment: My website is wamp based. So I've got both `htaccess.conf` and `.htaccess` files. `htaccess.conf` is into C:\_Wamp_Path_\wampstack-5.5.28-0\apps\wordpress\conf\ and `.htaccess` is into my \htdocs\MySiteFolder\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Marc B's comment, simply create an `.htaccess` file in `SubFolder_B` and add the following line:

```
DirectoryIndex master.php
```

When you request `mydomain.com/SubFolder_A/SubFolder_B/`, `master.php` will load by default.

Comment: When I request mydomain.com/SubFolder_A/SubFolder_B/ , master.php is loaded now. 
The address **www.mydomain.com/SubFolder_A/SubFolder_B/** is showed in the browser. Could I show **www.mydomain.com** only?

Comment: Please mark this is accepted, as it does answer the original question. Regarding your second question, you will need to use a `RerwriteRule` to mask requests made to the domain root to the subfolder's `master.php` file. In your root `.htaccess`, use `RewriteRule ^$ /SubFolder_A/SubFolder_B/master.php [L]`.